# Slow performance for textpath in Firefox

Tags: d3.js, svg

I was building some graph with d3. But I found the performance is very slow in Firefox when textpath was used. My page is rather complex and the app is running on ExtJs which make the HTML code even more complex.

It's a force directed graph, and the path is always redrawn on tick. Thus, I suspect that the browser is taking time to search for the element that was defined in the href in the textpath. (I assume it works like a query selector that search globally for the component).

Here's some code I just copy from other site for explanation purpose. My assumption is that the browser takes time looking for element with ID=wavy.

Is there any known performance issue on this matter in Firefox?

```js
//Create the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 120);

svg.append("path")
    .attr("id", "wavy") //Unique id of the path
    .attr("d", "M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Q 340,140 400,30") //SVG path
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "#AAAAAA");

//Create an SVG text element and append a textPath element
svg.append("text")
   .append("textPath") //append a textPath to the text element
    .attr("xlink:href", "#wavy") //place the ID of the path here
    .style("text-anchor","middle") //place the text halfway on the arc
    .attr("startOffset", "50%")
    .text("Yay, my text is on a wavy path")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here's are the actual rendered HTML of my code. (Hope it helps to illustrate my issue)

```html
<path id="passiveLink1f26b5e955511c894841ec7d0b5bf915" class="link-path graph-scale-invariant-stroke graph-scale-invariant-stroke-dasharray" d="M-74.49900293826057,50.5028004161668A150.000001,150.000001 0,0,1 75.50099806173942,50.5028004161668" style="stroke: rgb(127, 20, 30); fill: none; stroke-width: 2.39135; stroke-dasharray: 11.9568, 7.17405;"
  x1="-74.49900293826057" y1="50.5028004161668" x2="75.50099806173942" y2="50.5028004161668"></path>
 
<text>
<textPath xlink:href="#passiveLink1f26b5e955511c894841ec7d0b5bf915" startOffset="50%" dominant-baseline="central">➤</textPath>
</text>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a [<marker>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) instead of text?

Comment: Also what char are you using in javascript for the arrow? I would use `\u27a4`

Comment: I use ➤ which i think it's \u27a4

Comment: I used <marker> marker-mid but for some reason, it's not working in firefox